# How to turn display from none to block in Scrapy?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape data from a drop down menu(Here is the [link](https://portal.orio.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?urlRequestType=Base&productId=31426&catalogId=10051&categoryId=146334&errorViewName=ProductDisplayErrorView&urlLangId=-150&langId=-150&top_category=146332&parent_category_rn=146332&storeId=11901)). During inspecting to get the xpath, I realized that the display is none. So is there any way to scrape data from that drop down manu(Fits the following cars) who's display has set to none. If yes/no, how/why?

Answer (score 1):

The data you want to scrape gets populated via Ajax call. So, you need to find out the url of the Ajax call. Once, you get that ,your work is easy.

Follow the steps below.

1. Open Chrome
2. Open the link
3. Open Developers console
4. Go to network tab
5. Now click on "Fits the following cars"
6. In the network tab ,see the call happening

In your case, it's a post request that happens over the fly.

Here is the pic of the call

[image]

Therefore, you need to find the url and the request parameters passed during the request.

You can see that the request parameters are as follows:

1. catentryId: 31426
2. techDocId: 33503

Now you got the url and data, it's just a matter of few lines of code.

Comment: Thanks. But how can it be a matter of few lines of code.Would you like to add few line of code in your answer for more understanding. How to pass request parameters to get the link?

Comment: Will you please add an example code? I searched a lot about how to implement that information and got nothing except headache.