# How to move to the next page,during Scraping, if both pages have the same link?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to scrape the website([link](https://portal.orio.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/SearchDisplayView?storeId=11901&catalogId=10051&langId=-150&pageView=detailed&beginIndex=0&sType=SimpleSearch&categoryId=146003&showResultsPage=true&navCat=146002_146001&urlLangId=-150&removeFiltersOg=ALL&sortField=name&orderBy=7)). I've scraped all the data from this page using for loop and yield function as

```
def parse(self, response):
    self.main_cat=response.xpath('//div[@id="products_content"]/div/text()').extract()
    self.sub_cat=response.xpath('//div[@class="accordion"]/div[@class="title"]/text()').extract()
    Onclick=response.xpath('//div[@class="accordion"]/div[@class="no_title subtitle_chck"]/@onclick').extract()
    for index in range(len(Onclick)):
        sub_sub_cat=response.xpath('//div[@class="accordion"]/div[@class="no_title subtitle_chck"]/label/text()').extract_first()
        removeSearchWord=Onclick[index].replace("submitSearch(","")
        numericData=removeSearchWord.replace(");","").split(',')
        absolute_url="https://portal.orio.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/SearchDisplayView?storeId=11901&catalogId=10051&langId=-150&pageView=detailed&beginIndex=0&sType=SimpleSearch&categoryId="+numericData[0]+"&showResultsPage=true&navCat="+numericData[1]+"_"+numericData[2]+"&urlLangId=-150&removeFiltersOg=ALL&sortField=name&orderBy=7"
        yield Request(absolute_url, callback=self.page)

def page(self,response):
    product_page_url=response.xpath('//td[@class="information"]/a/@href').extract()
    for url in product_page_url:
        yield Request(url, callback=self.product)
```

After the last yield function, which line of code leads me to continue scraping all the other pages. I know there needs some ajax calls but I don't know about how to implement for them. Would you like to add that line of code because I tried much to find the solution and my last question was also about this which was answered very well but I didn't get that.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the next page url is right there. 
It's `<a>` node that contains `<img>` node with image `paging_next.png`:

if you look at that node you can see there's onclick javascript script attached that changes browser url to the next page url:
[image]
You can extract that with xpath selector and some regex:

```
url = response.xpath('//a[contains(img/@src,"paging_next")]/@onclick').re("setPage\('(.+?)'")[0]
Out[1]: 'https://portal.orio.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/AjaxCatalogSearchResultView?pageView=detailed&searchTermScope=&orderBy=7&categoryId=146003&beginIndex=25&pageSize=25&maxPrice=&searchType=1002&sortField=name&resultCatEntryType=&searchTerm=&sType=SimpleSearch&filterTerm=&manufacturer=&catalogId=10051&langId=-150&showResultsPage=true&storeId=11901&metaData=YnV5YWJsZToxPE1UQFNQPi1zdXBlcnNlc3Npb246KDEgMyA3KSBBTkQgcHJpY2VfU0VLXzIxOlsqIFRPICpdIEFORCAtcHJpY2VfU0VLXzIxOlsqIFRPIDBdPE1UQFNQPnB1Ymxpc2hlZDox&minPrice='
```

It's an ugly url but it works in scrapy just fine :)

General pagination logic looks something like this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    product_urls = ...
    for url in product_urls:
        yield Request(url, self.parse_product)
    # next page
    next_page = ...  
    if next_page:
        yield Request(next_page, self.parse)
    else:
        self.log('oh no, last page was: {}'.format(response.url), level=logging.INFO)
```

Comment: Thanks. this way of getting the url will only leads to 2nd page. What about 3rd page?

Comment: Once you crawl page2 you look page3 url in it. See my edit to understand common pagination loop in scrapy.

Comment: You can see there are 125 products and this way of scraping will on produce data of 50 products(two pages).

Comment: @DanyalMughal I'm not sure if I understand you but you'll have to figure out the rest on your own. I explained how to get next page and how to develop a pagination loop in scrapy - this example does work, you just need to put all the pieces together yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I'd appreciate your help. Will you please come to my previous question which was answered but I didn't get it(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49955430/how-to-turn-display-from-none-to-block-in-scrapy/49955604#49955604)